# How can be cout \Process(sqlservr)\% Processor Time over 300 %

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server, perfmon

The counter, Process(sqlservr)\% Processor Time, is hovering around 361% on one of my database servers. This counter reflects the percent of total time SQL Server spent running on CPU (user mode + privilege mode).

Number of CPU's  - 2

\\Process(sqlservr)\% Processor Time MAX - 361.35

\\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time - 100

No.of.CPU's 2 = Processor _Total(100 * 2 = 200),How is it possible for that counter to be over 300%?

Comment: what's the processor? i.e. exact model

Comment: and is hyperthreading enabled?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean 2 physical CPUs (usually referred to as 2 sockets), or a single CPU with 2 cores?

I'm guessing you may have 2 physical CPUs (sockets) and each is dual core, which effectively gives you 4 CPUs, making your maximum for the counter 400%.

Comment: We have  2 Physical CPU's only ..

Comment: I mean 2 processors only

Comment: I have given below the processor details ..AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 254

2 Physical Processors / One Core / One Logical Processor / 64 bits

Comment: Property Value
CPU Name AMD Opteron 254 (2P) Property Value
Platform Name Socket 940

Comment: Odd, that's a single-core CPU with no hyperthreading, you really should only see two cores - very odd

Comment: Hyperthreading not enabled..

Comment: yes,Its very odd, how do identify the reason

Comment: That's quite bizarre. How many CPUs does Device Manager show?

Comment: Two Processors only

Comment: I have given below  CPU details,S version - Windows Server 2003, (64 bit) Standard Edition Service Pack 2
Database version - Microsoft SQL Server 2005 9.3.4035.00
Number of CPU(s) - AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 254 2 Physical Processors / One Core / One Logical Processor / 64 bits
CPU Name-AMD Opteron 254 (2P)
CPU Code Name - Troy
Platform Name - Socket 940